# Creating a Next button for switching through jQuery tabs

Tags: jquery, html, tabs, jquery-tabs

How can I create a button that will scroll to the next jQuery tab. I want to have a next button within the tabs that will scroll to the next tab, sort of like a step-by-step tutorial.

How can this be done? My code so far is below.

HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-3"><span>Three</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fragment-1">
        <p>First tab is active by default:</p> <a href="nexttab">Next Tab</a>
    </div>
    <div id="fragment-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh</div>
    <div id="fragment-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the [`selected` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-selected) to move around, like this:

```
$(".nexttab").click(function() {
    var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
    $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
});
```

Just change your anchor to match, like this:

```
<a class="nexttab" href="#">Next Tab</a>
```

[You can view a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/RaaDV/)

---

Alternatively, make each "Next Tab" link point to a specific tab and use the [`select` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-select), like this:

```
<a class="nexttab" href="#fragment-2">Next Tab</a>
```

Then you can use a bit shorter jQuery, and move to any tab you want:

```
$(".nexttab").click(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs("select", this.hash);
});
```

[Here's a demo of this approach](http://jsfiddle.net/RaaDV/1/)

Comment: this.hash is the best answer I have seen. +1

Comment: please make a circular navigation!

Comment: Even though this is an old answer, but can somebody explain me what does, and why `this.hash` works?

Answer (score 13):

I found that with UI 1.10.0 this solution no longer works, as "selected" was deprecated.  The following will work in both 1.10 and earlier versions-

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$(".nexttab").click(function() {
    var active = $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active" );
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", active + 1 );

});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer @user1431891 !
Do not use selected anymore - instead use the [active option](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Nick Craver's answer, here's how I produced the same functionality using next-buttons that look like this in the HTML at the bottom within each tab div:

```
<button class="btnNext" style="float:right">Next</button>
```

Based on Nick's answer I created two functions:

```
function moveToNextTab()
{
        var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
        $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
}
function EnableButtons(className)
{
    //Enable Next buttons
    var aryButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for(var i = 0; i < aryButton.length; i++)
    {
        var e = aryButton[i];
        if(e.className == className)
        {
            e.onclick = function()
            {
                moveToNextTab();
                return false;
            };
        }
    }   
}
```

Since each button belongs to the "btnNext" class, after the page loads, I call:

```
onload = EnableButtons("btnNext");
```

and this enables each button's ability to move to the next tab.